# Liferay 7.4 - access structure data in ftl template

Tags: json, field, liferay-7

in previous Liferay version this was approach to access structure data fields (title, subtitle) but lately liferay migraten from xml to json, so this does not work

```
 journalArticle = assetRenderer.getArticle()
 docXml = saxReaderUtil.read(journalArticle.getContent())
 articleTitle = docXml.valueOf("//dynamic-element[@name='title']/dynamic-content/text()")
 articleSubTitle = docXml.valueOf("//dynamic-element[@name='subtitle']/dynamic-content/text()")
```

I tried to access json

```
 docJSON = jsonFactoryUtil.convertXMLtoJSONMLArray(journalArticle.getContent())
```

But it does not work.
How to access these fields now?

this is how json array looked like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a web content structure with two text fields: joboffering and workplace (this last one is repeatable). Note that in Liferay 7.4 the name you assign to a field is stored as *"field-reference"* attribute; in previous versions the name you assigned to a field was stored as *"name"* attribute.

I then created the following widget template for asset publisher (for simplicity I just rendered the first entry), that worked as expected:

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#assign entry = entries[0] 
        assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer()
        journalArticle = assetRenderer.getArticle()
        docXML = saxReaderUtil.read(journalArticle.getDocument().asXML())
                     
        docJSON = jsonFactoryUtil.convertXMLtoJSONMLObject(journalArticle.getDocument().asXML())
        joboffering = docXML.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@field-reference='joboffering']/dynamic-content").getText()
        workplaces = docXML.selectNodes("/root/dynamic-element[@field-reference='workplace']/dynamic-content")
    />
    <h1>
        ${joboffering} 
    </h1>
    <ul>
    <#list workplaces as workplace>
        <li>${workplace.text}</li>
        </#list>
    </ul>
    <code>${docJSON}</code>
</#if>
```

The XPath query is then

```
/root/dynamic-element[@field-reference='joboffering']/dynamic-content
```

for the first field (note that I used the `field-reference` attribute), and

```
/root/dynamic-element[@field-reference='workplace']/dynamic-content
```

for the second. This second XPath is executed in the `selectNodes()` method and the result is printed through a loop.

I also printed the json version of the content.